# Solving triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have to solve the integral $$ \int_{0}^{R}dz \int_{0}^{R} dy \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}dx$$
 of the function $x^2+y^2+z^2$ .

My problem is that $dz$ and $dy$ are not at the end, so I cannot use other coordinate transformations, e.g. in cylindric $dxdydz = \rho d\rho d\phi dz$

How do I deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

When calculating
$$\int_{0}^{R}dz \int_{0}^{R} dy \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}dx(x^2+y^2+z^2),$$
you can integrate consecutively with respect to each variable, no need to integrate with respect to $dx\,dy\,dz$. In your example you obtain
$$\int_{0}^{R}dz \int_{0}^{R} dy \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}dx(x^2+y^2+z^2) =\int_{0}^{R}dz \int_{0}^{R} dy \left(\frac{x^3}{3}\Big|_{x=0}^{x=\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}+(y^2+z^2) \sqrt{R^2-y^2} \right)$$ and then continue with integrating with respect to $dy$ and $dz$.

Another approach would be to examine the region where you are integrating: $0\le z\le R$, $0\le x$, $0\le y$, $x^2+y^2\le R$, which strongly suggests the cylinder coordinates: $$x= r\cos \phi\\y=r\sin \phi\\z=z.$$

In these coordinates your integral becomes

$$\int_0^Rdz \int_0^R rdr\int_0^{\pi/2} (z^2+r^2)d\phi,$$which should be even easier to find.

Comment: What is the idea behind $dy = rdr$ ? My approach would work like this:
$$y = r\sin\phi$$
$$ \frac{dy}{dr} = \sin\phi $$
$$ dy = \sin\phi dr $$

Comment: @Christian no, you forgot about $dx$. So you get $dx= \cos \phi \,dr-r\sin\phi d\phi$, $dy= \sin \phi dr+r\cos\phi d\phi$, hence $dx\wedge dy = r\,dr$. I already applied the Fubini theorem here.

Comment: sorry, I still don't get it 100%.
I see it has to do something with functional matrix of Jacobi. But why?

Comment: @Christian whenever you change variables in integration, you have to work with the Jacobi matrix (more precisely, with its determinant). In our case the Jacobi matrix writes $\begin{pmatrix}\cos \phi&-r\sin\phi\\\sin\phi&r\cos\phi\end{pmatrix}$, and its determinant is $r$.

Comment: I still dont understand 100%. Nevermind, probably i am just too tired ... I'll have a look at it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not losing yourself with not much? Note that $$ \int_{0}^{R}dz \int_{0}^{R} dy \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}dx\,(x^2+y^2+z^2)=\int_{0}^{R}\left(\int_{0}^{R} \left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}(x^2+y^2+z^2)dx\right) dy\right) dz,$$ and that $$\int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}(x^2+y^2+z^2)dx\,dy=\iint_D(r^2+z^2)\,r\,dr\,d\theta,$$ where $D$ is the quarter of a disk defined in polar coordinates by $$D=\{(r,\theta)\mid 0\leqslant r\leqslant R,\,0\leqslant\theta\leqslant\tfrac\pi2\}.$$

Comment: I think you forgot about the function the author needed to integrate...

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I had indeed. Thanks for notifying me.